# Am I calling this javascript method from php correctly?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to call a Javascript method defined in a file from php. But somehow I just cant get it to work. Any thoughts would be appreciated

PHP

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='like.js'></script>";
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'test();', '</script>';
```

And in `like.js` I do

```
function test(){
alert("Hello");
}
```

However the alert doesnt show up . I know that the path to `like.js` is correct because I can see the source in Firebug. Im sorta new to PHP, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have public, protected or private visibility like PHP. Also, what's the point of the comma separated strings in the second echo? Use a single string.

Comment: Removed it, but the alert still doesnt show up

Comment: Just so that you don't get the false impression: You are not calling JavaScript from PHP. All you do is create the HTML which contains JavaScript, and which is later on interpreted and executed by the browser.

Comment: check your firebug console, most likely the path "URL" of your javascript file is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public keyword in JavaScript.

Your function in like.js should look like this:

```
function test() {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

You could test if your files are set up correctly using this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>function test() { alert('Hello'); }</script>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'test();', '</script>';
```

If that code works, then your files are not set up correctly.

Comment: No unforunately its on localhost

Answer (score 0):

I bet that the URL for your like.js is wrong, open firebug and checkout the console and see the error that is being displayed, this should take you to the right direction as how to fix the error, if like.js location was wrong you may do the following:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mywebsite.com/js/like.js'></script>";
```

instead of:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='like.js'></script>";
```

Hope this helps